# How to create tables in a specific database in a DB2 for z/OS subsystem using T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, db2

Below T-SQL only creates table in the schema of current user, not the database specified. Why?

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( URI VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PARENT_URI VARCHAR(255) , 
TITLE VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, MIMETYPE VARCHAR(100) , DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(1000) , 
MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(1000)) IN DATABASE DB4TEST;
```

The table can be created, but I can only see it in current user's default schema, not in the database I specified. The database does exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the two concepts of schema and database.

A DB2 database can contain multiple schemas.

If you want the table to be created inside SCHEMA DB4TEST in the DATABASE DB4TEST, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE DB4TEST.TEST ( URI VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PARENT_URI VARCHAR(255) , 
TITLE VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, MIMETYPE VARCHAR(100) , DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(1000) , 
MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(1000)) IN DATABASE DB4TEST;
```

Comment: Thanks, actually after reading more online help I realized it's not recommended to have more than one table in a database in DB2 for z/OS.

Comment: @Bruce Li:  In DB2 for z/OS, you typically have *many* tables in a given database.  However, people tend to define only one table per *tablespace*.  I wonder if that is what you meant?

Comment: @bporter: Please read the Recommendation information on this(Recommendation) page.